# Rally: Possible to go deep in a query?

Tags: extjs, rally

I have this code to query the Snapshot Store:

```
Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore',{
        autoLoad: true,
        fetch: ['Iteration','ObjectID','Name','_ItemHierarchy','_UnformattedID'],
        sorters: {property: 'Iteration', direction: 'DESC'},
        filters: query,
        listeners: {
            load: function(store,data,success){
                console.log("POID ",prefixed_story_children," exploring ",data);
                if(data[0].data.Iteration.length!=0)
                    me._get_name_of_iteration(data[0].data.Iteration,prefixed_story_children);
                else{
                    console.log("no iteration for ",prefixed_story_children);
                    me._update_iteration_of_parent(prefixed_story_children,null);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Is it possible to fetch the details of Iteration while querying? For example:

```
fetch = ['Iteration[Name,_refObjectName,StartDate,EndDate]','Name','FormattedID'].
```

I vaguely remember there was some way I could deep query in Rally that would allow me to do this. I had seen it in one of the sdk versions but can't remember. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a SnapshotStore that gets data from LookbackAPI, and it does not store Name, EndDate and StartDate of iterations. It only stores the OID.
A fetch like this

```
fetch    : ['Name','Iteration', 'StartDate', 'EndDate']
```

on a user story object will work with WsapiDataStore.